# cant click on Button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, twitter

I'm trying to log into my twitter account by using selenium. The filling of username and password is working perfectly, but when pressing the login-button nothing happens.

```
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div').click()
```

I looked into the html-code and the `aria-haspopup` is on false. Is there any way I can set it on true so I can click the button?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is working well on twitter's login page (https://twitter.com/login). Maybe you're trying to login on other page.

I'm providing small piece of code for logging into twitter. I used another xpaths  and WebDriverWait for waiting until login form would be displayed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='session[username_or_email]' and @data-focusable='true']")))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session[username_or_email]' and @data-focusable='true']").send_keys('login')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='session[password]' and @data-focusable='true']").send_keys('password')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='LoginForm_Login_Button']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')

email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
email.clear()
email.send_keys(EMAIL)
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'pass')
password.clear()
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # Login with ENTER button
```